# Couldn't create mapping policy for class named (Cocoa error 134110)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am doing a manual/heavy migration in Core Data. I have data models i.e. `myApp2.xcdatamodel` and `myApp3.xcdatamodel`.

`myApp3` has one new table (like junction table) in between two tables both of them were in `TO-MANY` relationship.

Moreover I have defined a `NSEntityMigrationPolicy`. Now when I run with this custom policy (which was particularly written for relationship and manage the data) I get this error specifically when calling `migrationManager.migrateStoreFromURL`

```
Optional("Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 \"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134110.)\" UserInfo=0x7feda0d825b0 {NSUnderlyingException=Couldn\'t create mapping policy for class named (MyTableToMyTablePolicy)}")
```

I have tried to look on this error but from one way or another it targets Policy class, which I have pasted below.

```
class MyTableToMyTablePolicy: NSEntityMigrationPolicy {

    override func createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance(sourceInstance: NSManagedObject, entityMapping mapping: NSEntityMapping, manager: NSMigrationManager, error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool {

        let sourceKeys:[AnyObject] = sourceInstance.entity.attributesByName.keys.array
        let sourceValues = sourceInstance.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(sourceKeys)

        let destinationInstance:NSManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(mapping.destinationEntityName!, inManagedObjectContext: manager.destinationContext) as NSManagedObject

        let destinationKeys = destinationInstance.entity.attributesByName.keys.array as [AnyObject]

        if mapping.userInfo!["modelVersion"]!.integerValue == 2 {

            for key in destinationKeys {
                let value:AnyObject = sourceValues[key as String]!
                if value.hasText() {
                    destinationInstance.setValue(value, forKey: key as String)
                }
            }

        }
        else { // call the super just
            super.createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance(sourceInstance, entityMapping: mapping, manager: manager, error: error)
        }

        manager.associateSourceInstance(sourceInstance, withDestinationInstance: destinationInstance, forEntityMapping: mapping)

        return true
    }
}
```

And following are the xcdatamodels myApp2 and myApp3 respectively:

[image: myApp2]

[image: myApp3]

**UPDATED:** Crash Log:

[image]

Comment: It says it could not create the migration policy. Do you need to prefix your custom migration policy name with the swift module ?

Comment: @k6sandeep Very good.

Comment: @Sandeep that was definitely the solution for me!

Answer (score -2):

First,

Doing a heavy migration on iOS is a **bad idea**(tm).  Heavy migration was not meant to be run on a device with limited CPU, limited memory and limited launch time.

Second,

You are probably only showing part of the error.  Can you show the entire error stack?  Usually Core Data errors contain internal errors that you can print out via accessing the `-userInfo` dictionary.  That will give us a deeper understanding of the error.

Last,

Where is the debugger breaking at?  What line is throwing the error?

Comment: 1) I should avoid heavy migrations on iOS? 
2 & 3) The error is all I get. Before it, following line is shown on debugger: "CoreData: annotation: Disconnecting from sqlite database." The error is thrown by the &error parameter passed in migrateStoreFromURL of NSMigrationManager object. (The issue is resolved. I was missing module name as it is needed in Swift now to work. Thanks to @k6sandeep)

Comment: Glad it is resolved.  Yes you should avoid a heavy migration on iOS.  The heavy migration was not designed to run on iOS.  It runs there more by accident than by design.  As for your error; there is a `-userInfo` contained *within* the `error` variable that will give you the sub errors.  That is what I was asking you to print out.

Comment: Yes. Progressively migrate also have risk of infinite recursion which can freeze iOS device if mistaken as heavy migration is really lengthy stuff (also happened to me). UserInfo=0x7feda0d825b0. I have also updated the question with crash log for further study with all information. Thanks to you.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra When a lightweight migration is not possible is there an alternative to a heavy migration?

Comment: @Simple99 Yes, export and then import or retrieve the data from the source again.  Export/Import is the answer if the data is unrecoverable.

Comment: So if heavy migration is bad, how do I change an attribute type from String to Double without heavy migration?

Comment: Create a new property that is a double (myValueDbl) and then either do the conversion lazily or do it after the lightweight migration.  But first, I would attempt a lightweight migration as it is constantly improving.